# AndEngine and old android versions

Tags: android, andengine

Which is the oldest version of andrioid that I could use with AndEngine GLES2.0? 
Is there a problem with android's emulator because the application stops working whenever I try to open it with a version below android 4?

Answer (score 1):

Try running andengine application in [BLUESTACK](http://www.bluestacks.com/) emulator , that will work fine.